# jquery validation error messages placement

Tags: jquery, validation, properties, html

I have some span elements with different error messages. They are with `display:none` style, and I would like to change this property to "inline" instead of showing an error message.

These are my rules

```
$().ready(function() {
 
 // validate signup form on keyup and submit
 $("#form").validate({
  rules: {
   telephone: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 9,
    maxlength: 9,
    number: true
   },
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }
      
  },
  messages: {
   telephone: {
    required: "The telephone is required",
    minlength: "The must have at least 9 digits"
   },
   email: "Please enter a valid email"
   });
});
```

My span elements looks like this:

```
<span id="telephoneerror" class="infoerror" style="display:none">The telephone is required</span>
<span id="telephonelenghterror" class="infoerror" style="display:none">The must have at least 9 digits</span>
```

I'm very beginner with jQuery.

Thanks.

Comment: $('#telephoneerror').css('display','inline');

Comment: And [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is a link to full documentation.

Comment: thanks Morteza Edalati, I´ve been looking at th documentation before posting, but I don´t know exactly where to add this code.

Answer (score 0):

You have different way to do that

1. addClass

   $('#telephoneerror').addClass('myclass');
2. attr

   $('#telephoneerror').attr('style','display:inline-block');
3. css

   $('#telephoneerror').css('display','inline-block');

Comment: thanks... but I dont know where should I add the code.

I tried to write it instead messages section, but it doesn´t works  :(